# Simple calculator with specific methods and multiple classes - Java

Tags: java, class, methods, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator that uses specific methods and classes. The following methods are given:

```java
public class App {

    private static final Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static String getString(String prompt) {  }

    private static double getDouble(String prompt) {  }
}
```

It must have a separate `Calculator2` class that contains the code for add, sub, mult, divide.

The program is supposed to look like:

```
What would you like to do? 
Add
Subtract 
Multiply 
Divide
Exit
*user inputs*
What is the first number:
*user inputs*
What is the second number:
*user inputs*
Result:
```

I am really struggling with how to call the `Calculator2` class, especially with the specific requirement of the String method. I have tried multiple approaches (`else if`, `switch`, calling for only the first letter to make it a char, etc.) and nothing is working. My most recent attempt I tried to get the user input and convert that into char so I could use a switch method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;


public class App {

    private static final Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("add");
        System.out.println("subtract");
        System.out.println("multiply");
        System.out.println("divide");
        System.out.println("exit");
        String operator = inputScanner.nextLine();
        Double userInput = getDouble();
        Double math = getString();
    }

    private static double getString() {
        char choice = operator.charAt(0);
        switch (choice) {
            case 'a':
                calculator2Object.add();
                System.out.println();
                return result = operator;
                break;
            case 's':
                calculator2Object.subtract();
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 'm':
                calculator2Object.multiply();
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 'd':
                calculator2Object.divide();
                System.out.println();
                break;
            case 'e':
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private static double getDouble() {
       System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
       double firstNumber = inputScanner.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
       double secondNumber = inputScanner.nextDouble();
       return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
}
```

Here is the `Calculator2` class:

```java
public class Calculator2 {
        double add(double firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
            double result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }

        double subtract(double firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
            double result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }

        double multiply(double firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
            double result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }

        double divide(double firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
            double result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

These are my errors:

```
cannot find symbol variable operator
cannot find symbol variable calculator2Object
cannot find symbol variable result
```

Comment: In the `getString` method, you haven't declared the  `operator`,  `result` and `calculator2Object` variables.

Comment: What is the user supposed to enter in response to _What would you like to do?_ Do they enter the first letter, i.e. one of A, S, M, D or E? Do they enter in upper-case or lower-case (or either)? Or do they enter the whole word, e.g. "Add". Must the user input be case sensitive, i.e. do they have to enter "Add" or can they enter "add"? I understand that this is an assignment, so are you restricted in what parts of Java you are allowed to use?

Comment: `calculator2Object.add();` - isnt this part missing parameters? there are a couple more problems in your program but i am not sure where to start. perhaps writing it in a simple one `main` method then reduce them bit by bit into subroutines will be easier(?)

Answer (score 0):

> cannot find symbol variable operator

This error was caused by `char choice = operator.charAt(0);` in your `getString(string)` method. The `operator` is not declared in that context and it only available to the `main` method.

> cannot find symbol variable calculator2Object

The `calculator2Object` inside `getString(string)` is not declared and instantiated anywhere in the method previously. You should instantiate the variable before using it (e.g. `Calculator2 calculator2Object = new Calculator2();`). Alternatively, just set `double add(double, double)` as `static`.

> cannot find symbol variable result

Triggered by `return result = operator;`, the `result` variable is not declared at all in the `getString(string)` method. Remember, stuff inside `Calculator2` methods can't be accessed by `getString(string)` unless its a property or `return`-ed.

---

The reason I suggested for trying to build up the code from the main method then divide them up as you find repetitive code is so that you have a working sample and to learn about variable scopes.

Looking at the given boiler plate, I suspect it was to accomodate most of the repetitive part of the code: asking user input.

```
private static final Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

private static String getString(String prompt) {  }

private static double getDouble(String prompt) {  }
```

Think this way, if you did not use the `getString(string)` or `getDouble(string)`, you may end up having multiple of:

```
System.out.println("What is the first number:");
double operand = Double.parseDouble(inputScanner.nextLine());
```

If you complete the `getDouble(string)` into:

```
private static String getDouble(String prompt)
{
    System.out.println(prompt);
    return Double.parseDouble(inputScanner.nextLine());
}
```

You can prompt while assigning the result into variable by doing the following instead:

```
double operand = getDouble("What is the first number:");
```

You can complete the `getString(string)` in similar fashion - its optional anyway.

The next part would be calling the appropriate method in `Calculator2`. You could simply turn the method into `static`. So that you can call them using `Calculator2.add(operand1, operand2)` directly from the `main` method.

```
static double add(double firstNumber, double secondNumber) {
    double result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Once you have completed those fixes, your main method will be (kinda) shorter - arguably you can get even shorter and more efficient though.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String operator = getString("What would you like to do?");
    char choice = operator.charAt(0);
    switch (choice) {
        case 'a':
            double operand1 = getDouble("Enter the first number:");
            double operand2 = getDouble("Enter the second number:");
            Calculator2.add(operand1, operand2);
            break;
                //the other operators
        case 'e':
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Half working fiddle: https://onecompiler.com/java/3zqmgapkx

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me pinpoint concepts I need to get a better understanding on.